# Is it true that $\frac{1}{\cosh(x) - \sinh(x)} = e^{x}$?

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

Is it true that:

$$\frac{1}{\cosh(x) - \sinh(x)} = e^{x}$$

Graphically, it seems to be true, but I am not sure if it is true for all $x$.

Also, if it is, is it a known result?

Comment: Yes. It is true...

Comment: Do you know how to express cosh and sinh in terms of the exponential function? There are simple formulae which split $e^x$ into its even and odd parts. Use these and you will be able to check it out for yourself.

Comment: Ah, nice. @johannesvalks

Comment: What are the definitions of $\cosh$ and $\sinh$ you're using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\cosh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$$

$$\sinh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$$

$$\cosh(x)-\sinh(x)=e^{-x}$$

$$\frac{1}{\cosh(x)-\sinh(x)}=e^{x}$$

Answer (score 4):

Recall:

- $e^x = \cosh x + \sinh x$.
- $(\cosh x)^2 - (\sinh x)^2 =1$.

And do not forget
 $a^2 - b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$.

Answer (score 3):

Just use $\cosh{x}=\tfrac12(e^x+e^{-x})$ and $\sinh{x}=\tfrac12(e^{x}-e^{-x})$

Answer (score 3):

Yep. Use the well-known identities:
$$ \cosh x = \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2} \textrm{ and } \sinh x = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2} $$

This is sort of analogous to $\cos x - i \sin x = e^{-ix}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \mathrm{cosh} x = \dfrac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}, \ \mathrm{sinh} x = \dfrac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2} $$
It follows from this and the fact that the denominator is non-zero for all real $x$, that the equality is true.

Answer (score 1):

We have, $\cosh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$, also, $\sinh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$. So, $\cosh(x)-\sinh(x)=e^{-x}$ or $\frac{1}{\cosh(x)-\sinh(x)}=e^x$. Yes, it is well known.